# Referencing cells from other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract data from different sheets in a summary sheet.

The referencing does not work.

```vb
Sub Summary_LPI()

  Dim wkSht As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet, rngSearch As Range
  Dim shNCell As Range

  Set wsC = Sheets("Summary")
  Set rngSearch = wsC.Range("A2:A60")
  For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'find the sheet name cell in rngSearch:
    Set shNCell = rngSearch.Find(what:=wkSht.Name, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, 
   MatchCase:=False)
    'if found:
   If Not shNCell Is Nothing Then
      'copy the below built array in the necessary place
      wkSht.Range("AZ56").Value = wsC.Range(shNCell.Offset(0, 6), shNCell.Offset(1, 6)).Value
     
    End If
Next wkSht

End Sub
```

[image: Referencing]

Comment: `shNCell` is a cel/range in sheet `wkSht`. You cannot use it to set a range in `wsC` one (`wsC.Range(shNCell.Offset(0, 6),...`). Are you sure that need copying from "Summary" to iterated sheet?

Comment: If you really need copying in that way, you can use `shNCell.Offset(0, 6).Address`.

Comment: Please include in your question a description of what your actual goal ist. What exactly has to be copied and where exactly do you want it to be pasted. That's not clear your code does something different than your images suggest. • What's your expected outcome?

Comment: No, instead I need copying from the iterated sheets to summary sheets. Can you share the correct code

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Data Into a Summary Worksheet

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- The order of the columns in the Summary worksheet needs to be the same as in each individual worksheet.
- The number of columns to be pulled is defined by the last non-empty column in the first (header) row of the Summary worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Summary_LPI()
        
    ' s - Source, d - Destination
    
    Const sfvCol As String = "AY" ' First Value Column

    Const dName As String = "Summary"
    Const dlCol As String = "A" ' Lookup Column
    Const dfvColString As String = "F" ' First Value Column
    Const dhRow As Long = 1 ' Header Row
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim dfRow As Long: dfRow = dhRow + 1 ' First Row
    Dim dlrow As Long ' Last Row
    dlrow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If dlrow < dfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim dlcrg As Range ' Lookup Column Range
    Set dlcrg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol), dws.Cells(dlrow, dlCol))
    
    Dim dfvCol As Long: dfvCol = dws.Columns(dfvColString).Column
    Dim dlvCol As Long ' Last Value Column
    dlvCol = dws.Cells(dhRow, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If dlvCol < dfvCol Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim vcCount As Long: vcCount = dlvCol - dfvCol + 1 ' Value Columns Count
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim svrrg As Range ' Value Row Range
    Dim svRow As Long ' Value Row
    Dim dvrrg As Range ' Value Row Range
    Dim dlCell As Range ' Lookup Cell
    
    For Each dlCell In dlcrg.Cells
        Set dvrrg = dlCell.EntireRow.Columns(dfvCol).Resize(, vcCount)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set sws = wb.Worksheets(CStr(dlCell.Value))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
            dvrrg.ClearContents ' remove if you want to keep the previous
        Else ' worksheet exists
            svRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sfvCol).End(xlUp).Row
            Set svrrg = sws.Cells(svRow, sfvCol).Resize(, vcCount)
            dvrrg.Value = svrrg.Value
            Set sws = Nothing
        End If
    Next dlCell
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Summary updated."

End Sub
```